# Sharing configmap in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to share a configmap between two services (let's say A and B)

- A and B are in the same namespace
- They both get deployed with Helm
- They have some common configurations that should be in the same Configmap
- They also have their some private configurations that don't need to be shared

***What i have done so far:***

- I have created a new repo in the same namespace with A and B, let's call it **ABCommons**
- I am deploying a configmap with **ABCommons** containing the shared configurations

***My Questions:***

- How can I refer - and use the configmap deployed by ABCommons from A and B ?
- How can I use [this](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments) feature to restart A and B when the configmap from ABCommons gets updated, while they're in separate repositories ?
- How can I merge the configmap from **ABCommons** and also A's private configmap together to use it in A ?

Kind regards and thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple ConfigMaps and that might be the easiest approach here.

In a Helm context, you'd have to pass the name of the external ConfigMap as a parameter (as a Helm value, with `helm install -f` or `helm install --set`).  Where you use the ConfigMap values, you can then refer to that value name.

```yaml
env:
  - name: FROM_COMMON_VALUES
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: {{ .Values.externalConfigMap }}
        key: commonValue
  - name: FROM_OWN_CHART
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}
        key: something
```

```bash
helm install --set externalConfigMap=abcommons a .
```

In Helm, another option is to allow each chart to be installed independently, but to provide the common values as configuration to both.  This would avoid the shared ConfigMap, and in turn would allow the two services to be deployed into separate namespaces.

```yaml
# charts/a/templates/configmap.yaml
data:
  commonValue: {{ .Values.commonValue }}
  something: {{ .Values.something }}
```

```yaml
# charts/a/values.yaml

# commonValue describes the common value both charts use.
commonValue: default value for commonValue

# something describes a setting specific to this chart.
something: value
```

```yaml
# values.common.yaml
commonValue: shared between both charts
```

```yaml
helm install \
  --namespace a \
  -f values.common.yaml \
  a ./charts/a

helm install \
  --namespace b \
  -f values.common.yaml
  b ./charts/b
```

Comment: helm upgrade --install --dry-run test helmcharts/elastic-schema --set externalConfigMap=orgs=src/main/resources/test .

Ran the above command 

Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]


I'm not sure what I'm missing here

helm version:
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.12.2", GitCommit:"1e210a2c8cc5117d1055bfaa5d40f51bbc2e345e", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.20.6"}